# How to delete default profile property "Assistant"

Tags: user-profile-property

How to delete profile property "[Assistant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147513.aspx)" ?

From Central Admin or powershell.

Right now when i delete this property i get an error message:

> delete operation failed. Please try again later. If the  problem
>   persists, contact your administrator.

log:

```
MgrProperty.DeleteProperty(): Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.CommitFailedException: L’appel de procédure stockée de la mise à jour de propriétés a renvoyé une erreur. Code d’erreur : 4. Erreurs lors de la suppression des propriétés : 1. Erreurs lors de la mise à jour ou de la création des propriétés : 0.     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBase.Update(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, IEnumerable addPropertyList, IEnumerable updatePropertyList, IEnumerable removePropertyList)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBaseManager`1.Remove(T property)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypePropertyManager.Remove(String propertyURI, String propertyName, String sectionName)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.Us...
MgrProperty.DeleteProperty(): Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.CommitFailedException: L’appel de procédure stockée de la mise à jour de propriétés a renvoyé une erreur. Code d’erreur : 4. Erreurs lors de la suppression des propriétés : 1. Erreurs lors de la mise à jour ou de la création des propriétés : 0.     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBase.Update(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, IEnumerable addPropertyList, IEnumerable updatePropertyList, IEnumerable removePropertyList)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBaseManager`1.Remove(T property)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypePropertyManager.Remove(String propertyURI, String propertyName, String sectionName)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.Us...
MgrProperty.DeleteProperty(): Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.CommitFailedException: L’appel de procédure stockée de la mise à jour de propriétés a renvoyé une erreur. Code d’erreur : 4. Erreurs lors de la suppression des propriétés : 1. Erreurs lors de la mise à jour ou de la création des propriétés : 0.     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBase.Update(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, IEnumerable addPropertyList, IEnumerable updatePropertyList, IEnumerable removePropertyList)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBaseManager`1.Remove(T property)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypePropertyManager.Remove(String propertyURI, String propertyName, String sectionName)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.Us...
MgrProperty.DeleteProperty(): Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.CommitFailedException: L’appel de procédure stockée de la mise à jour de propriétés a renvoyé une erreur. Code d’erreur : 4. Erreurs lors de la suppression des propriétés : 1. Erreurs lors de la mise à jour ou de la création des propriétés : 0.     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBase.Update(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy, Guid partitionID, IEnumerable addPropertyList, IEnumerable updatePropertyList, IEnumerable removePropertyList)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyBaseManager`1.Remove(T property)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypePropertyManager.Remove(String propertyURI, String propertyName, String sectionName)     à Microsoft.Office.Server.Us...
```

Comment: Try to find detail information about this error in ULS log (exception, stack trace) and post here.

Comment: updated my initial post with the error in the log file

Answer (score 1):

The answer is because you don't have the right security rights.

See
http://www.hezser.de/blog/2013/02/08/cannot-delete-user-profile-property-in-sharepoint-2013/